# Use multiple collectionfixture on my test class in xUnit 2.x

Tags: xunit, xunit.net

I am writing test cases for my `DataAccessRepository` ( using entity framework) class. This class takes two argument in constructor.

1. connection object
2. Automapper object

Now, I am using collectionFixture in xunit to pass DatabaseFixture in my test class but I need to pass AutoMapper Fixture as well to the same test class. I tried adding two collection, one after another but it is not valid.  Can someone please throw some light on how to use more than one FixtureCollection on a test class in xunit.

My Unit test class looks as follows and it is throwing error as I can not use two CollectionFixture attribute on the class,

```
[Collection(Traits.DatabaseFixtureCollection)]
[Collection(Traits.AutomapperFixtureCollection)]
public class MyAssessmentRepositoryTests
{
    private readonly IMyAssessmentsRepository _Repo;
    public MyAssessmentRepositoryTests(DatabaseFixture dbFixture,AutomapperFixture amFixture)             
    {
        this._Repo = new MyAssessmentRepository(dbFixture.IcmDbContext,amFixture.Mapper);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have a single collection, which will declare that the collection provides two different `ICollectionFixture<X>`s

Comment: Thanks. I did the way you suggested and created the object for both fixture in my single collection constructor. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context

A single test class can only be in *one* Test Collection (which is why there is such a constraint on the Attribute).

The solution is to declare a single 'virtual' Test Collection, which declares the two fixtures that a test in such a collection should have controlled access to via `ICollectionFixture<X>`s.

When this is in place, the Test Class ctor is furnished with any of the Fixture instances as needed.

(You can also use an `IClassFixture` at the Test Class level to declare stuff outside of the Collection [but such Fixtures will be spun up/down] per execution of tests in that Test Class as opposed to ones at Test Collection level which will be spun up/down just the once for the entire run and handed to all Test Classes in the collection as they take their turn to access the Collection Fixture])

Comment: The problem with me is that I have multiple databases with multiple fixtures for each. I also need to initialize my mapper only once.